# Silence Sqlplus Login Message but Retain Echo

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus

Running a series of automated checks on our databases for the security folks checking our STIG compliance. Mostly simple stuff like certain parameters turned off, etc. We're in the stone ages, so this is being done with Sqlplus scripting to populate the reports.

Using sqlplus -S to filter out that unnecessary login message, but the security folks would also like the command with the finding details instead of just the output. With sqlplus -S, the output is

```
VALUE
------
FALSE
```

whereas we want

```
Select blah blah;

VALUE
------
FALSE
```

Set echo on doesn't fix this, even when nesting the query in a sql script and run with @. I'm assuming the S option overrides the echo setting. Wondering if there's an option I'm not familiar with or if I just need to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

'sqlplus -S' suppresses banners, prompts, and echoing commands.

Cheers,

Russ